# Height of arbitrary point on circle segment

Tags: math, geometry, computational-geometry

Given a circle segment with radius `r` and chord length `d`:

How can I compute the height `h` over the chord of a circle point depending on angle `alpha`?

[image: Arc segment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
h = r sin(α+ß) - c
```

where

```
c = √(r²-d²/4)
```

and

```
sin(ß) = c / r
```

Comment: What is $\beta$? The only given values are $\alpha$, $r$, and $d$.

Comment: I think I got it. beta = asin(c/r). Using sin(a+b) = sin a * cos b + cos a * sin b, the thing can be made even more simple...